# Android: AndEngine Null Pointer Error

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using AndEngine to make a game. Right now, I have an `ArrayList` populated with several `Sprite` objects. I have another `Sprite` that I was to check collisions against, and then remove the `Sprite` in the `ArrayList` after a small delay. However, I think I'm going about this wrong since I'm getting a null pointer error on my `ArrayList`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mIceArray.size(); i++) {
    if (this.collidesWith(mIceArray.get(i))) {
        final int mIndex = i;
        TimerHandler iceRemovalTimer = new TimerHandler(0.1f, new ITimerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                removeIce(mIceArray.get(mIndex));
                mIceArray.remove(mIndex);
                unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                }
        });
        mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(iceRemovalTimer);
    }
}
```

If anyone has suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: This code is inside my other Sprite's `onManagedUpdate()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post your error log, and where you init your `mIceArray`. But I anticipated your problem:

You try to modify your `mIceArray` during iterating through it based on collision states and a timer. This will trick your mind for runtime debugging. The causes may be:

- Your `mIceArray` is not initiated before your sprite is updated on the Scene.
- Error is pulled out from `mIceArray.get(index)` lines while item at index is already removed.

To do so, you use:

```
synchronized (mIceArray)
{
    for(....)
    {
        //your code to check mIceArray
        //and store (mark) the object to be removed from array
    }
    //remove obj outside the for loop
}
```

Why don't you try AndEngine solutions:

- **`CollisionHandler`** with **`ICollisionCallback`** for Scene collision checking, or
- **`ContactListner`** for Physcis collision handling.